# Select rows with maximum column value distinct column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with data as fleet table data:

[image]

I'm trying to get the MAX `aircraft_count` for each `carriercode` along with the rest of the columns.

I know this works but I can't get the rest of the columns

```
select carriercode, max(aircraft_count) as peak
from fleet
group by carriercode;
```

This is the closest I have come.

```
select f1.id, distinct(f1.carriercode), f1.aircraft_count, f1."timestamp"
from fleet f1
where f1.aircraft_count = 
    (select max(f2.aircraft_count)
     from fleet f2
     where f1.carriercode = f2.carriercode)
order by f1.aircraft_count desc;
```

Expected result:

```
id - carriercode - max_count - timestamp
10 - EIN         - 100       - 2016-03-27 23:07:49.121449
252 -SCO         - 34        - 2016-03-27 23:07:53.282367
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (f.carriercode) f.*
from fleet f
order by carriercode, aircraft_count desc;
```

This returns one row per `carriercode`, the one with the highest `aircraft_count`.  If there are ties, then an arbitrary row is selected.

If you want all rows with matches, then `distinct on` doesn't quite work.  Instead:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by carrier_code order by aircraft_count desc) as seqnum
      from fleet f
     ) f
where seqnum = 1;
```